# prediction io - manage or clear events

Tags: predictionio

A few questions:

1. Suppose that I train the PIO system with a bunch of events, but then I find out that my events were wrong for some reason, and I want the system to ignore or delete these events the next time I train it. How can I do it without deleting the entire database for my app?
2. The events flowing into the PIO server add up to billions. Do you have to regularly delete old events from the system, and if so, how? do you run queries directly against HBase or are there special PIO commands for that?
3. In the installation process I saw that PIO uses both HBase and Elastic Search. What does it store in Elastic Search?

Code samples would be very helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of PredicionIo do you use? (apache or actionml) and which template?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you ask about the universal template.

1. You can change the engine.json and remove those event types. So do you effectively ignored.
2. See - eventWindow in [here](https://github.com/pferrel/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation)
3. Hbase is used to save the events data and elasticsearch is used to save the metadata of the items. You can see this in the configuration file `pio-env.sh`

Please note that this universal template version (0.3.0) requires PredicitionIo from ActionML fork version 0.9.6.

Comment: Thanks. I also wanted to ask if there's a way to distribute the storage and computational load across multiple PIO servers. I can't find instructions how to do it anywhere.